# Como agrupar datas de acordo com o mês? Ruby + MongoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

Possuo uma classe que contém eventos e suas datas de início. Eu preciso resgatar todos os registros, agrupando-os de forma que sejam listados os primeiros dias de cada vez. Exemplo:

```
2014-01-01, 2014-02-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-01-02, 2014-02-02, 2014-03-02, ...
```

Preciso desses resultados, pra montar a estrutura de um calendário.
Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Segue a classe.

```
class Headline
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :start_date, type: Date
  field :end_date, type: Date

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Vocé pode definir um `scope` e a partir dele retornar os objetos ordenados por data de inicio, como exemplo:

[MongoID](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#order_by)

```
MongoID
# Provide the sorting options.
Person.order_by([[:first_name, :asc], [:last_name, :desc]])
```

ou:

```
scope :start_date, :order => (:start_date, :asc)
```

Comment: Obrigado, Jean. Só que o meu problema é que eu tenho a seguinte estrutura: https://gist.github.com/derickhoganpimenta/5ec709708d53df51a92c.
Essa é a estrutura de um calendario, formado à partir das datas dos eventos. Cada <tr>, representa uma única data de cada mês. Sendo assim, tenho que exibir algo assim: 
`<tr>
  <td>01-01</td>
  <td>01-02</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>02-01</td>
  <td>02-02</td>
</tr>`
Então, a forma que eu pensei para resolver esse problema, é agrupar os resultados, trazendo sempre as primeiras datas, depois as segundas datas, e assim sucessivamente de cada mês. Ideias?

Answer (score 0):

Pra agrupar e ordernar objetos ruby:

```rb
headlines.group_by { |h| h.start_date.day }
  .values
  .map { |hs|
    hs.sort_by { |h| h.start_date }
  }
```

Se a ideia é delegar a responsabilidade de agrupamento e ordenação pra query do banco de dados, um approach como esse para o MongoDB pode ser útil: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19713564/1512161